# Call functions from another file AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

How can i call a function from another file in AngularJs? I'm going to use the same header in all my pages, so i need to call the functions that lives in it.

This is my code so far. First, my index:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="adminApp">

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Admin test</title>
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link type="text/css" href="app/css/admin.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link type="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.standalone.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<head>

    <base href="/">

</head>
<body>

    <div ng-include="'app/components/include/header.html'"></div>

    <ng-view></ng-view>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.js"></script>
<script src="app/components/home/admin-home.js"></script>
<script src="app/components/include/header.js"></script>
<script src="app/factory/admin-factory.js"></script>
<script src="app/routes/admin-route.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Then the app.js:

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('adminApp', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute']);
})();
```

The HTML for the header:

```
<section class="admin-header">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
            <h1>Admin test</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" id="login" align="center">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-user" ng-click="open()">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<div class="menu-out">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-logout">Logout</button>
</div>
```

Everything until here is ok. Now my doubt is how to call a funtion to toggle the `.menu-out` div if the header will be separated as all the pages that will live in it?

I've tried with the file header.js like this:

```
(function(){

    var head = {
        templateUrl: '/app/components/include/header.html',
        controller: headCtrl
    };

    angular
        .module('adminApp')
        .component([], head);

    headCtrl.$inject = ["$scope"];
    function headCtrl($scope){

        $scope.open = function(){
            $('.menu-out').toggle();
        }

    }

})();
```

But is not working. As you can see i've added the brackets in component, 'cause i don't know if i need to call the header from the `routes.js` file.

This is the route.js file:

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('adminApp')
        .config(config);

    config.$inject = ["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider"];
    function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');

        $routeProvider

            .when('/', {
                template: '<admin-home></admin-home>'
            })

            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
    }

})();
```

I need to use `$rootScope`? Someone can guide me please. As i've said, i'm using AngularJs, HTML and Javscript.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of the `module.component` method should be a string to name the component:

```
angular
    .module('adminApp')
    ̶.̶c̶o̶m̶p̶o̶n̶e̶n̶t̶(̶[̶]̶,̶ ̶h̶e̶a̶d̶)̶;̶
    .component("adminHome", head);
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS angular.module Type API Reference - component](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#component)